# Transpose non-duplicated edge list into symmetrical matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have an edge list with similarity values that I need to transpose into a symmetrical matrix. For example, my raw data is in a data frame with a format like this:

```
example <- data.frame(Source = c(0,4,2,2,5,0,1,3,0,10,6,11,7,2),
                  Target = c(1,6,12,13,13,14,14,15,17,17,20,23,24,25),
                  Similarity = c(0.004,0.0009,0.007,0.02,0.0011,0.0018,0.011,0.0013,0.006,0.005,0.0006,0.005,0.0026,0.0013))
```

I need to somehow get this into a matrix where the rules are:

1. Intersection between "Source" x "Target" = Similarity
2. IF "Source" == "Target" THEN 1.00
3. IF there is no similarity score for a combination of "Source" x "Target" values then populate the intersection with 0

In the end, the data should look something like this:

```
     0      1     2     3     4     5
0   1.0   0.004   0     0     0     0
1  0.004   1.0    0     0     0     0
2    0      0    1.0    0     0     0
3    0      0     0    1.0    0     0
4    0      0     0     0    1.0    0
5    0      0     0     0     0    1.0
```

The actual matrix won't be quite that sparse and will have ~30,000 rows x 30,000 columns. I'm unsure how to approach this. I can put the existing data into a matrix format easily enough. I can fill missing values with 0 easily enough. But turning the raw data into a symmetrical matrix and populating the diagonal with 1.0 while all other missing values get populated with 0 is beyond me.

EDIT: Maybe a simpler way to ask this is 'How would I make a symmetrical matrix from this data'

```
example <- data.frame(Source = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                      Target = c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5),
                      Similarity = c(0.004,0.0009,0.007,0.02,0.0011,0.0018,0.011,0.006))
```

Comment: Obed, are you able to make your desired output the actual desired output from your sample data? It's quite confusing at the moment to know where your row names and column names are coming from. You have no `Target` equal to zero in your example data. Do we assume there is supposed to be one since the diagonal is full of 1s?

Comment: @AllanCameron that's part of the difficulty. The raw data does not have data for the diagonal (1,1; 2,2; 3,3; etc.) Likewise, if it has 1,2 then it will NOT have 2,1. So the desired output above is actually what I would like. I just truncated it at 5 rather than going all the way up to 25 to save space.

Comment: @AllanCameron I just added another example. Maybe it's clearer?

Comment: I think I've got it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diag` to get an identity matrix and then fill the cells symmetrically with a loop. We have to add a one to all the indexes because your matrix is zero-indexed. Note that this example prints the first column in scientific notation, but you can see it is the same as the first row.

```r
mat <- diag(max(c(example$Source, example$Target)) + 1)

for(i in 1:nrow(example))
{
  mat[example$Source[i] + 1, example$Target[i] + 1] <- example$Similarity[i]
  mat[example$Target[i] + 1, example$Source[i] + 1] <- example$Similarity[i]
}

dimnames(mat) <- list(Source = 0:max(example), Target = 0:max(example))

mat
#>       Target
#> Source     0      1      2      3     4     5
#>      0 1e+00 0.0040 0.0009 0.0070 0.020 0.000
#>      1 4e-03 1.0000 0.0011 0.0018 0.011 0.006
#>      2 9e-04 0.0011 1.0000 0.0000 0.000 0.000
#>      3 7e-03 0.0018 0.0000 1.0000 0.000 0.000
#>      4 2e-02 0.0110 0.0000 0.0000 1.000 0.000
#>      5 0e+00 0.0060 0.0000 0.0000 0.000 1.000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a cool solution. How would you go about labeling the rows/columns of the output matrix? For example "1" instead of [1,]. I'm eventually going to use this matrix for PCA and/or TSNE and want to use row names to label the marks on the resulting graphs.

Comment: @Obed yes! Ironically that was what I showed you to do in my answer to your last question, which you unaccepted earlier today! I have included it again here.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I didn't mean to unaccept your previous answer. There was another answer that worked as well. Didn't realize doing so would unaccept yours!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `Matrix` library

eg

```
library(Matrix)

A <- sparseMatrix(i = example$Source + 1, 
                  j = example$Target + 1,
                  x = example$Similarity, symmetric = TRUE)
diag(A) <- 1


head(A)
6 x 26 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                                                                                                 
[1,] 1.000 0.004 . . . . .      . . . . . .     .      0.0018 .      . 0.006 . . . . . . . .     
[2,] 0.004 1.000 . . . . .      . . . . . .     .      0.0110 .      . .     . . . . . . . .     
[3,] .     .     1 . . . .      . . . . . 0.007 0.0200 .      .      . .     . . . . . . . 0.0013
[4,] .     .     . 1 . . .      . . . . . .     .      .      0.0013 . .     . . . . . . . .     
[5,] .     .     . . 1 .  9e-04 . . . . . .     .      .      .      . .     . . . . . . . .     
[6,] .     .     . . . 1 .      . . . . . .     0.0011 .      .      . .     . . . . . . . .
```

if you want you can coerce `A` to a normal matrix by doing `as.matrix(A)`

Comment: Is there any way to assign dimnames to output matrix? For instance, I tried `dimnames(A) <- list(Source = unique(example$Source), Target = unique(example$Target))` but get an error

Comment: @Obed there is a parameter called dimnames inside the `sparseMatrix` function. Look into that